# Issue creating instance of BigqueryService

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, google-bigquery

I am using ASP.NET MVC with Google Big Query. I am using Google.Apis.Bigquery.v2 nuget package.

I am creating an instance of BigqueryService object using,

```
    private async Task<BigqueryService> GetBigqueryServiceAsync()
    {

            var ms = new MemoryStream();
            var filePath = _pathService.MapPath("~/App_Data/bigquery.p12");
            await _fileService.CopyToStreamAsync(filePath, ms);
            var certificate = new X509Certificate2(ms.GetBuffer(), _settings.GoogleCloudServicePassword, X509KeyStorageFlags.Exportable);
            var credential = new ServiceAccountCredential(new ServiceAccountCredential.Initializer(_settings.GoogleCloudServiceEmail)
            {
                Scopes = new[] {BigqueryService.Scope.Bigquery, BigqueryService.Scope.CloudPlatform}
            }.FromCertificate(certificate));
            var bigqueryService = new BigqueryService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
            {
                HttpClientInitializer = credential
            });
```

This method is working but the problem is that whenever I need to call Google Big Query then I need to execute this method which is same for all requests so I thought I should make it singleton. But when I try to use Lazy its failing,

```
static readonly Lazy<BigqueryService> BigqueryServiceInstance = new Lazy<BigqueryService>(() => GetBigqueryServiceAsync);
```

It shows me compile error. Note my _pathService is intance variable.

Comment: I'm not a C# programmer, but it looks like the problem may be that GetBigqueryServiceAsync is a Task<BigQueryService> but the Lazy<> requires a raw BigQueryService. I think you might want to do await in your lambda.

Comment: @JordanTigani, I have found AsyncLazy Thanks.

Comment: Hey, I'm interested in "make it singleton". I searched on Lazy but cannot find how it can help to make it singleton? Will this still create a new BigQueryService instance everytime when you call it?